# Clear color with Xcode8 and iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I Just install Xcode 8 and I have a problem with clear color... 
I have a `UINavigationBar` and `UITableView` and I want they are translucent.

For my Navigation bar I tried to check translucent in Interface Builder or by the code, I don't have my bar transparent... it's Black !

For my `UITableView` I tried by the Interface Builder and by the code with `backgroundColor` and `UIColor.clear` or Color literal. It's the same thing I have a black background ! :/

It's worked fine before with Xcode 7, and now, with Xcode 8 and iOS 10 it's not working anymore...

My Code:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @pedrouan my code : `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear` `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`